# why is this behaviour of strtof() changes with respect to the change in stdlib.h?

Tags: c, libraries

With `<stdlib.h>` included the following code gives the output of `123.34`.

```
#include<stdlib.h>  
int main()
{
    char *str="123.34";
    float f= strtof(str,NULL);
    printf("%f",f);
}
```

But without `<stdlib.h>` it produces the output of 33.000000.

What is the role of `<stdlib.h>` here and why did the value 33.00000 occur when it is nowhere in the code?

Comment: I am getting 123.34996 on my PC including the lib header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must take a look at the warning generated by the compiler.

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'strtof' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

This still yields result, which is not deterministic in any way because the return type expected is `float`, whereas without the header inclusion, the default is assumed to be `int`.

If you look into the [stdlib header file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdlib.h.html), there is a declaration,

```
float strtof(const char *restrict, char **restrict);
```

With `#include<stdlib.h>`, we provide this declaration. When missed, compiler assumes to be returning `int`, and hence the result is not deterministic.
With my system, it produced `0.00000000` as the output, whereas with the necessary inclusions, I got `123.339996` as the output.

As a precaution, make a habit of always compiling the code with `-Wall` option (Assuming that you are using gcc), or better yet, `-Werror` option.

Answer (score 1):

The `<stdlib.h>` header tells the compiler that `strtof()` returns a `float()`; in its absence, the compiler is forced to assume it returns an `int`.  Modern C compilers (GCC 5 and above) complain about the absence of a declaration for `strtof()` and/or a conflict with its internal memorized declaration for `strtof()`.

If you omit `<stdlib.h>`, your code is unacceptable in C99 and C11 because you didn't declare `strtof()` before using it.  Since you omit `<stdio.h>`, it is invalid in C90, let alone C99 or C11.  You must declare variadic functions such as `printf()` before using them.